# How to apply custom master page to application page in 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, custom-masterpage, application-pages

After upgrading a 2010 site to 2013 in 2010 UI mode, I'm unable to apply a custom master page to application (_layouts) pages.  The custom master page has been configured as the Site and System master page and shows up correctly throughout the site whether logged in or not.  However, I have a custom login page, e.g.

```
/_layouts/MyPages/Login.aspx
```

And the master page is not being applied there as it was prior to upgrading.
I have tried both of these variants in the Page declaration:

```
DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"
DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/custom.master"
```

It reverts to `/_layouts/simplev4.master either way.`

Update: switching from having the page inherit from IdentityModelSignInPageBase to instead use UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase solved this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute "DynamicMasterPageFile" will attempt to read from the Master Pages configured on the Web.

I would start by checking out which Master Pages are set under Site Settings (or using PowerShell, checking the value of the SPWeb object for the Master Page's Urls).

Another alternative would be to hardcode the Master page you want to use by replacing the "DynamicMasterPageFile" for "MasterPageFile" and pointing to the _catalogs, as explained here:

http://mmman.itgroove.net/2012/08/24/using-a-page-specific-master-page-in-sharepoint-2010/

Additionally, I would check the "MasterPageReferenceEnabled" status, and that your Application Page inherits from "LayoutsPageBase" as explained in this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537530(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Application pages don't belong to any particular web, do they?  Regardless, I did check the master page paths on the root web and they are correctly pointing to my custom master page.  I tried the suggestion in your link and got this error: The file '/_layouts/MyPages/~site/_catalogs/masterpage/mymasterpage.master' does not exist.

Comment: Application pages do not belong to any particular web.

Comment: Your URL doesn't look correct. Try "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/mymasterpage.master"

Comment: I have verified MasterPageReferenceEnabled is true on the web application.  I tried your master page URL (DynamicMasterPageFile="~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/mymasterpage.master") and received this error:  Content controls are allowed only in content page that references a master page.

Comment: Try MasterPageFile="~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/mymasterpage.master‌​". Also, I don't know the code you have on your ApplicationPage, so the error showing there might be "valid" depending on whether you have the correct syntax in the Page's content (i.e. everything should be inside ContentPlaceHolder)

Comment: Can you check whether your Application Page inherits from LayoutsPageBase or not? The DynamicMasterPageFile would only work if it inherits from it. This link also shows exactly what happens behind the scenes: https://kkryczka.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/sharepoint-2010-setting-up-master-page/

Comment: I originally tried MasterPageFile="..." as suggested but it produced the same sort of error as in my first comment.  The ~sitecollection token doesn't appear to get replaced.  The page inherits from UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.

Comment: Do the "<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">" look with the proper capitalization "asp:Content"? If they are lower case you'll get the error you pasted on the comment.

Comment: Correction, it actually inherits from IdentityModelSignInPageBase.  I actually tried removing all content from the page.  The error goes away but it still reverts back to simplev4.master.  I even tried pasting v4.master into my custom master page to rule out issues in that markup.  At a loss.

Comment: This is a sample I have that works: "<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="InactiveAccounts.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages.InactiveAccounts" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/custom.master" %>

Code behind: public partial class InactiveAccounts : LayoutsPageBase

Comment: Can you try simplifying your scenario to use "LayoutsPageBase"? You should try to simplify this as much as possible, to reduce the possible points of failure to the minimum.

Comment: It does work properly when inheriting from LayoutsPageBase, thanks.  Now to figure out why it does not work with IdentityModelSignInPageBase.